# Add a custom class to the body tag using custom fields

Tags: php, custom-field, hooks, post-meta

There are certain posts where I want to manually append a custom body class using custom fields.

How do I go about it appending the class to the body tag when a certain custom field is added to a post?

I have tried the following but the custom fields name `tagbody` is not shown in the dropdown:

```
add_filter( 'body_tag', 'body_tag_name' );
add_filter( 'get_the_body_tag_name', 'body_tag_name' );

function body_tag_name( $name ) {
    global $post;

    $btag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tagbody', true );

    if ( $btag )
        $name = $btag;

    return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `body_class` filter.

```
function prefix_add_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    // good to check
    if( ! is_single() || 'post' !== get_post_type() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $btag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tagbody', true );

    if ( empty( $btag ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $classes[] = $btag;

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'prefix_add_body_class' )
```

EDIT:

You wrote me in the comments that the theme is your own theme. So you don't need to do it via a filter. Just do it right in your theme.

Edit the header.php file like this.

```
// some code above
$classes = array();

if( is_single() && 'post' === get_post_type() ) {
    $btag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tagbody', true );

    if( ! empty( $btag ) ) {
        $classes[] = $btag;
    }
}
?>
<body <?php body_class( $classes ); ?>>
<?php
// some code below
```

Comment: After adding the above to my `functions.php` file, how do I add the value to the post Emertop? Will the body class be the inputted value for $btag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The value loaded to the $btag variable will be inputed to the class of body tag. It's a filter, it's the way how you can change various values across WP.

Comment: So whatever value I assigned to the btag field will be added as the post body class right?

Comment: Exactly. But there is one condition, your theme have to call body_class function in body tag. But each good theme do this so it should work everytime. You can check header.php file in your theme if it's there. If not, just add it to the body tag like this 

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

Comment: I build the theme from scratch myself Emertrop. This is the body tag right now: `<body <?php body_class( $class ); ?>>`

Comment: It has body_class but there's a $class inside. Is that ok?

Comment: I don't know your theme but you can pass some classes to the body_class function too. And if you're building your own theme, maybe it would be better approach to pass it already there than do the same think with the filter.

Comment: Is that easier than the above? If yes, how do I do it Emetrop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26635/discussion-between-emetrop-and-andrew-lyndem).

Comment: I added this: `function prefix_add_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    // good to check
    if( ! is_single() || 'post' !== get_post_type() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $btag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tagbody', true );

    if ( empty( $btag ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $classes[] = $btag;

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'prefix_add_body_class' );` to my `functions.php` file but it's still not working Emetrop.

Comment: I added a custom field named `btag` with value `no-ad` but the value is not added to the body tag.